# Applied animations not running in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, css-animations

Below is my .css portion where I applied some animations on an element 'cog':

```
 .active-svg #cog {
    animation: cog 5s linear infinite;
    transform-origin: 75% 75%;
}

@keyframes cog {

    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes cog {

    from {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

It works fine in FF and Chrome and even upon inspecting this particular element in IE it is present over there but unlike other browsers, it doesn't animate. Any idea as to why it is not animating even though its applied?

Answer (score 0):

It works Perfectly In IE 11.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: example 5s linear infinite;
 transform-origin: 75% 75%;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    
    from {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>

<div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not on my end?